# Dúvida PHP Json Array

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Na query abaixo

```
$id_candidato = 1;
$id_vaga = 2; 

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidatos WHERE id_vaga = '".$id_vaga."' AND id_candidato = '".$id_candidato."'");

if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $registro = array(
            "ID" => $row['id'],
            "VAGA" => $row['id_vaga'],
            "ID_CANDIDATO" => $row['id_candidato']
        );

        $retorno[] = $registro;

    }
    $mysqli->close();
    $retorno = json_encode($retorno);
    echo $retorno;

}else {
    echo "nao existe";
}
```

eu obtenho o seguinte retorno:

```
[{"ID":"1","VAGA":"2","ID_CANDIDATO":"1"},{"ID":"2","VAGA":"2","ID_CANDIDATO":"1"}]
```

Minha questão é como faço para que o retorno seja exibido do modo abaixo?

```
[{"ID":"1","VAGA":"2","ID_CANDIDATO":"1", "ID":"2","VAGA":"2","ID_CANDIDATO":"1"}]
```

Comment: cara, pode explicar a necessidade disso? porque, ainda não cheguei a ver algum json nesse formato. o encode ai recebe um array e devolve conjunto de dados assim como ele recebeu do array.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago opa, preciso pegar VAGA num mesmo índice na resposta do angularjs. Ex: var resposta = response.data[0].VAGA;

Comment: E o que haveria de errado em ter `var resposta = response.data[0].VAGA` e também `var resposta = response.data[1].VAGA`? Múltiplos campos com o mesmo nome dentro de um mesmo objeto JSON não é algo que o javascript vai conseguir interpretar corretamente de forma nenhuma.

Comment: mas no caso, você só teria um registro com campos repetdos... `{"ID":"1","ID":"2"}`, olha, como teria um registro com dois campos iguais?

Comment: você garante que está enviando esse conjunto de dados para essa variável  `data`no angular da forma correta?

Comment: dá uma debugada pra verificar

Comment: Tá tudo certo. Preciso armazenar em um $scope só para fazer o forEach

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago Pesquisando percebi que funciona com arrays aninhados. Se quiser melhorar minhas resposta fique a vontade. Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, percebi que fazendo arrays aninhados consigo fazer o loop corretamente no angularjs. Não sei se é a melhor maneira de escrever o script mas ficou desta forma:

```
$id_candidato = 1;
$id_vaga = 2; 

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM candidatos WHERE id_vaga = '".$id_vaga."' AND id_candidato = '".$id_candidato."'");

if($sql->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $registro = array(
        "ID" => $row['id'],
        "VAGA" => [$row['id_vaga']],
        "ID_CANDIDATO" => $row['id_candidato']
    );

    $retorno[] = $registro;

}
  $mysqli->close();
  $retorno = json_encode($retorno);
  echo $retorno;

}else {
  echo "nao existe";
}
```

que me traz como resultado

```
[{"ID":"1","VAGA":["2"],"ID_CANDIDATO":"1"},{"ID":"2","VAGA":["2"],"ID_CANDIDATO":"1"}]
```